# Scrapy CrawlSpider and rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm begining with Scrapy and I made a couple of spiders attacking to the same site succesfully.

The first one gets the products listed in the entire site except their prices (because prices are hidden for not logged users) and the second one do login in the website.

My problem looks a bit weird, when I merge both codes: The result is not working! The main problem is that the rules aren't processed is like they aren't called by Scrapy.

Because the program have to login in the website, I have to override `start_requests` but when I override it the rules are not processed. I'm diving into the documentation but I don't understand how the methods/funcions are called by the framework and why the rules aren't processed.

Here is it my spider code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from oled.items import OledItem
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class OledMovilesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'webiste-spider'
    allowed_domains = ['website.com']

    rules = {
        # Para cada item
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(text(), '>')]'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//h2[@class="product-name"]/a')), callback='parse_item',
             follow=False)
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest('https://website.com/index.php?route=account/login',
                                 formdata={'email':'website@website.com','password':'website#'},
                                 callback=self.logged_in)]

    def logged_in(self, response):
        urls = ['https://gsmoled.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=33_61']
        print('antes de return')
        return [scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_item) for url in urls]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print("Dentro de Parse")
        open_in_browser(response)
        ml_item = OledItem()
        # info de producto
        ml_item['nombre'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//title/text())').extract_first()
        ml_item['descripcion'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="product-des"])').extract()
        ml_item['stock'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class=available])').extract()
        #ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(/html/body/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div/section[2]/ul/li[1]/span)').extract()
        #ml_item['categoria'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(/html/body/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div/section[2]/ul/li[2]/span)').extract()
        yield ml_item
```

Could someone tell me why the rules are not processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're bypassing the rules by overwriting the start_requests. The parse-method is never called, so the rules aren't processed.
If you want to process the rules for page https://gsmoled.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=33_61 after you're logged in, you can try changing the callback of the logged_in method to parse like this: `return [scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) for url in urls]`.

The rules should be processed at that moment, and because you specified 'parse_item' as a callback in the rules, the parse_item method will be executed for all urls generated by the rules.